# convert following MySQL query into Codeigniter Active Records

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I`m new to codeigniter and I like to convert following MySQL queries into Codeigniter Active Record Queries.

```
'SELECT name, address, detail, status, startdate, FROM job_step WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'  and 'status'===0'
```

P.S- job_step table consists of several columns, but I only need few not the entire table, addition to that information should filter according to session name and status (TINYINT which has 1 and 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the above query as:

```
$this->db->select('name, address, detail, status, startdate');
$this->db->where('username',$_SESSION['username']);
$this->db->where('status','0');
$rset=$this->db->get('job_step');
$result=$rset->result();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select('name, address, detail, status, startdate')
              ->from('job_step')
              ->where(array('username' => $_SESSION['username'], 'status' => 0))
              ->get()
              ->result();
```

This will get you an object. If you want array just change last line to `->result_array();`

Comment: Thank you for the quick respond, there is no error in the code, but nothing is returning..! My view is like this (I`m returning an array of data from the model)                                         `public function employees()
    {
        $this->load->model('show_details');  
        $result = $this->show_details->show_work();
     
            $data = array();
            $data['inbox'] = $this->show_details->show_work();
             echo "<pre>";
             print_r($data);
             echo "</pre>";
             die();`

Comment: you are saying that code is your view but it looks to me that it belongs to controller. Anyways, try `var_dump($data['inbox']);` and see if you get anything. And yeah, you should put that code in controller.

Comment: my bad it`s the controller indeed; After `var_dump($data[inbox]);` I get **NULL** as the result and empty array like this `Array([inbox] => )`

Comment: How about `var_dump($result);`. I see that you are using same function `show_work()` twice. So try that and if it doesn't work please post the `show_work()` function. I'm guessing that's your model function, right?

Comment: yes my model function `public function show_work() {
          $user_name = $this->session->userdata('username');
          $this->load->database();
          $this->db->select('name, address, detail, status, startdate');
          $this->db->where('name',$user_name);
          $this->db->where('status','0');
          $rset=$this->db->get('jobstage');
          $result=$rset->result();`

Comment: 2 things. Is your table name job_step or jobstage? In this question says job_step but in your show_work() function says jobstage. Another, if you want array out you need to use `result_array()` instead of `result()`

Comment: Result_array is the problem